# Customizing the Source URL (redirect URL) after a Workflow launched by a Quick Step in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I would like the Workflow to return to a List instead of my landing page after being initiated by a Quick Step.

After trying to sort this out in IE Dev Tools, the Quick Step button that initiates the Workflow called 'myWorkflow', it is javascript with what looks like the List GUID, ID, and Workflow Template ID.

I know I have to change the source Url, but I have no idea how to incorporate it into the Quick Step.

Comment: You are correct, you need to add the Source parameter to the URL in order to return to a particular location, however I do not believe you have that kind of control in a Quick Step.  Perhaps someone else has done this, but from what I have done with a Quick Step I am not sure it can be done.

Comment: Hmmm...thanks for the quick response. Any idea how I could kick off a workflow from a button using SP Designer 2013?

Answer (score 1):

I have never added a button, Mike Smith has a great write-up on how to do it.  Basically you add a button or link and then initiate the WF via a URL from there.  This allows you to add the Source parameter that will return you to a particular page.

Example: https://TheJDScottSite/sites/yourSite/wfsvc/20a711570d0549ff83adafde04bce160/WFInitForm.aspx?TemplateID={7032d6a6-66e0-4c22-9483-2971b90b0e64}&WF4=1&**Source=https%3A%2F%2FTheJDScottSite%2FLists%2FyourList%2FAllItems.aspx**

Hope this helps you further.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, it seems like we're back where we started because the WF Template ID changes every time a WF is run. That's precisely the reason I wanted to use a Quick Step (so I could circumvent that headache). Make sense? Thoughts?

Comment: It shouldn't.  Each WF has a constant WF Template.  The only thing that changes is the Workflow History Parent Instance (the instance of that WF that is running)  You don't need the dynamic ID to start the WF.

Comment: The link to Mike's write-up if you didn't find it is here: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.ca/2015/10/sharepoint-launch-site-workflow-from.html