# In SharePoint Designer 2010, create a button that when clicked updates a field and then rediredcts to a page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint Designer 2010 I have a Submit and Cancel Button, however I am trying to add an additional button which when clicked updates a field value and then redirects the page. How do you do this please?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information?  Where does the value come from?  Does the value need to come from user intervention (example: they have to fill in a field) or is it something like updating a status?

Comment: My bad , all items ( fields are from the same list). Updating status : When clicking on the button , let's call it "Reject" : Status changes to reject , triggers a workflow to send email and then the page is redirected to another page.

Comment: Do you want Reject button also to submit the entire form data filled ?

Comment: REJECT would just send everything as back to stage 1as is.

Comment: So to summerize, you need just the status to be saved as Reject ,and rest all fields should be retained as it was before opening the form

Comment: Yes  Gaurravs exactly... and to add ...redirect the page to a "reject page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the help of jQuery. Create a button and give it an ID. Then create a jQuery click event that does what you need to do.

For reference see the jQuery docu [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Example: In the HTML create a button like this

```
<button id="rejectButton">
  Reject this
</button>
```

Then add Javascript to the page with your preferred method (for e.g. via a CEWP linked file) that has code along the lines of

```
$( "#rejectButton" ).click(function() {
  alert( "The Reject button has been clicked." );
});
```

Instead of the alert, use jQuery or Javascript to set the value of your desired field, then submit and redirect to another page. There are plenty of code samples on the interwebs to do this. Just search for "sharepoint list redirect after submit" for a few ideas.

Comment: No need for separate code or jQuery, you can do ``<button onclick='javascript:{PUT ALL YOUR CODE HERE}'/>``

Comment: Thank you teylyn and Danny.
Please pardon my low knowledge of coding I will have to find out how to update a field - list item - using jquery.

Comment: @DannyEngelman jQuery will be a lot easier for identifying and manipulating the fields that need to be changed upon button click.

Comment: @MikeRooker, jQuery is for DOM manipulation and all sorts of stuff that can also be done with vanilla JavaScript, especially with modern browsers standardized on ES5 and ES6. For interaction with SharePoint you need JSOM (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh372944(v=office.14).aspx#odc_spe14_ta_WorkwithJSOM_ManipulatingData)

Answer (score 0):

I actually provided an answer to a question similar to this a couple of weeks ago.  It was for SP2013, but the steps should be similar in 2010.  Basically you want to create your workflow, get the GUID of the workflow, add a button to your form or ribbon and call the WF passing in a "Source" variable in the URL address, forcing the page to redirect as you require.

You can find the answer with more details at:
[Customizing the Source URL (redirect URL) after a Workflow launched by a Quick Step in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164953/customizing-the-source-url-redirect-url-after-a-workflow-launched-by-a-quick-s)

Hope this helps.